# Deep Link to Active Teams Meeting

Tags: microsoft-teams, deep-linking

I've managed to get Team Chat message to be issued through the following type link

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=,,..&message=

What I now want to do is to be able to do is to use this same URL technique to issue a request for someone to join an active meeting.

In otherwords, when a Meeting is currently running, there is an option to view participants, and then to invite participants directly from the meeting... All the Participant sees is a 'Accept / Decline" invite. Is there a similar URL/deep link type method that I can use use to initiate an  Accept/Decline invite?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there no deeplink to initiate an Accept/Decline invite. we recommend you to raise a Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Alternatively you can use [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-createorget?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request) to create or get online meeting and from response body you will get a `joinWebUrl`. Use that `joinWebUrl` to join an online meeting as deeplink.